# Should I do a regular system update before a upgrading to the next distro?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

Should I perform distribution upgrade only on a fully up to date system, or should it run fine if I do the distribution upgrade right away?

More details:

Before I perform an upgrade to the next version. I perform it first in a virtual machine to see it will be fine, and won't mess up anything.

When I booted my virtual machine it immediately popped up a window whether I want to upgrade it to 14.04. I clicked yes. It initially went fine then started to spew error popups about dependency problems.

The VM haven't booted up since the last upgrade to 12.04, 2 years. I suspect this caused the problem but not sure.

I worry I'd mess up the host if I get the same errors during upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ubuntu's own [site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) states that you should perform a regular update before upgrading your distro.

Furthermore, from personal experience, if you don't update beforehand the distro upgrade with have to perform the updates anyway. Part of upgrading distros is updating mass amounts of packages.